# Checking if all selects are completed in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count the number of VISIBLE selects (Which I've done in the alert in the Jquery) and also count the number of VISIBLE selects that have an option selected. If both numbers match then do some action.

Currently, when I change the first select and choose an option, it doesn't alert with a value. When I change the next select and choose an option it shows the count is 1 when it is meant to be 2. when I select the third select then it shows 3. However these numbers are all inaccurate. What is the cause of this?

```
<div id="secondPanelID">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <label for="gestationalAgeInWeeks">Gestational Age : </label>
        <div>
            <select id="gestationalAgeInWeeks" name="gestationalAgeInWeeks" class="form-control"> 
                        <option disabled selected value>SELECT</option>
                        <option value="0">0</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <label>days</label>
        <div>
            <select name=gestionalDays class="form-control">
                <option disabled selected value>SELECT</option>
                <option value="0">0 Days</option>
                <option value="1">1 Day</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added listeners to each of the selects

```
$("select[name=gestationalAgeInWeeks]").change(checkingColourSelectsGeneralData);
    $("select[name=gestionalDays]").change(checkingColourSelectsGeneralData);
```

Jquery

```
var selectCounterInGeneral = 0;
function checkingColourSelectsGeneralData(){
    alert($('#secondPanelID select:visible').length)
    $('#secondPanelID select:visible').change(function () {
      var o = $(this);
        if (!o.hasClass('counted')) {
        selectCounterInGeneral++;
        o.addClass('counted');
       }

      alert("number of selects: "+selectCounterInGeneral);
    });


}
```

Comment: Why do you do it so complicated? Just select all visible selects and on the other hand all visible selectes thats selected index is greater than zero and compare the amount of both collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if all visible selects have value this way:

```js
function countSelected(e) {
    var toReturn = true;
    $('select:visible').each(function(i) {
        if( !$(this).val() ) {
            toReturn = false;        
        };
    });
    console.log( toReturn );
};
$('select').on('change', countSelected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option disabled selected value>--choose--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option disabled selected value>--choose--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select style="display: none;">
    <option disabled selected value>--choose--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8zbpwk9/).

Comment: Simple and perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Could you also explain the  `e` and the `I` in the function please

Comment: `e` is event taken from `mousedown`, you can output to console to check what is inside `console.log(e)`. `i` is just a loop index, starting from zero.